# How to count items in one Colum matched to another Colum in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

help will be great here :)

I have one column "A" that holds a lot of product names
I have another column "B" that holds product types.
I want to know how many times one product type exists In the product names column.
the count result should be in a different column

Thanks!

Comment: Well at first glance you could use `COUNTIF`. For any further help some example data with expected results would be nice to see.

Comment: Do you want the count as a result, or do you want the matching values as a result?

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of the following examples:

`=COUNTIF(B1:B3,A1:A6)`
this shows the count of occurance of values in range `A1:A6` into range `B1:B3`. (Older versions of Excel need `=COUNTIF(B1:B3,A1)` and dragged down.)

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(COUNTIF(B1:B5,A1:A6)>0))`
this results in the number of instances the previous example formula returns a count not equal to 0.

`=FILTER(A1:A6,COUNTIF(B1:B3,A1:A6)>0)`
Office 365 required. This spills all values of range `A1:A6` that also occur into range `B1:B3`

Not sure what your end goal is, so I listed these 3 options.

[image]